# (TS 2556) Why am I recieving a type error on a spread argument that has already been explicitly typed and passed as a rest parameter?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-generics, async.js

```
function debouncePromise<TParams extends Array<unknown>, TRes>(
fn: (a: TParams) => Promise<TRes>,
  time: number,
) {
  let timerId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | undefined = undefined;

  return function debounced(...args: TParams) {
    if (timerId) {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      timerId = setTimeout(() => resolve(fn(...args)), time); //<= A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
    });
  };
}
```

I have already typed the spread argument in the function as a rest parameter. Why am I recieving an error on an argument/variable that has already been explicitly typed? How do I resolve this?

Update:
[tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgCYFMBGDJXQBQCcEBbOAZ3QB4AVfAQ0PpPOXQA8Z0JVWBBQkwCeVSAGsICAO4QAfABpkNAErpysgBTBkyEBABcyDfUN1GzcgEpkAXlnIipCtRVqF25PBLpDEMCUx0QnlgawBvDwAbdBhPOG9CAElUQ1UYMEIIGiEAB2oYXPQEEGRKGBp4orAYewAfZEgMEDgIdFRbBp50ZtbUAG5gD0IYjJRwaHgkNCwcaDaNADolxgBzclMGJhZwjx04Eo0vIOSdnTPkKGjGCu8cGEPKpNRLAfOAX13kYfTM5FapBzEMiUDQaYbkBCRABu6GsdmQEXOOiOTw6ZRuVXuGjh9nBkJhGj0i2WhDWlksiiOL0%20b2pOjeAw%20wCgSHIsQw2FwbQ6HNmeEcwPQoLgXG2tnsAucCzx0KFIvQ20UAA4AKwABheQA)

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] for this? (e.g. on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) or the like? And if you do, don't replace your code, just _add_ the link to that in your post). But in the absence of that: `fn` was declared as taking 1 argument, of type `TParams`, on line 2. But on line 12 you're _not_ passing it 1 argument of type `TParams`.

Comment: On line 2: fn: (a: TParams) => fn: (...a: TParams)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  ahhh i changed it to `fn: (...a: TParams) =>` and that resolved it! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a change in line 2
to `fn: (...a: TParams) =>` and that resolved it!